# Add text with a specific class to dropdown <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to

Get Text From Classes with class `.pick` and populate them into a dropdown `#pingList`

1) my Variable `picker` returns a long string, so I assume I need to create an array
2) `var array` I want the result to be `['x','y','z']` as I assume this is what I need in the next step.
3) I then want to add this to the dropdown with the `text` and `val` set.

I am pretty sure all I am missing is the array part. Looking for some help.

My Jquery Code and Live **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/UUY5Z/1/

```
// Get text from Pick CLass
var picker = $('.pick').text();

// Make an Array from string result above 
var array = //??

// Add this to the dropdown
$.each(array, function (val, text) {
$('#pingList').append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.text()` method returns `textContent` of all of the selected elements as one string, you can use `.map()` method instead which returns an array:

```
var picker = $('.pick').map(function(i, elem) {
     return "<option value='"+i+"'>" + 
               (elem.textContent || elem.innerText) + //  == $(elem).text()
            "</option>";
}).get(); // array of options (string)

$('#pingList').append(picker);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJsRd/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same like this.
No need to make an array.

```
$.each($('.pick'), function (val, text) {
    $('#pingList').append($('<option></option>').val($(this).text()).html($(this).text()));
});
```

JSFiddle For Same http://jsfiddle.net/sushilbharwani/uNpND/

Answer (score 1):

Here an other solution , using `$.each()` :

```
$.each($('.pick'),function(i, elem){
   $('#pingList').append( "<option value='"+i+"'>"+ $(elem).text() +"</option>"); 
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Y4r/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.pick').each(function(){

   $('#pinglist').append(""+$(this).text()+""); 

});
```

This should work for Above Case.

http://jsfiddle.net/sushilbharwani/uNpND/

Answer (score 1):

> I have updated in your demo page.. @http://jsfiddle.net/UUY5Z/7/

```
$(".pick").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    $('<option>').val(val).text(val).appendTo('#pingList');
});
```